# React Table v7 not populating with data when using useState within the component

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, react-table

Edit: final solution at the bottom.

I am trying to build a simple web-app to display some data stored in firestore database, using [React Table v7](https://react-table.tanstack.com/). I'm pretty new to React and javascript in general so forgive me if I use the wrong terminology.

At first I had put the function to fetch data inside `App.jsx`, passing it to state with `setState` within a `useEffect` hook, and it was working without an issue.

Then a colleague suggested that it is a good practice passing data to a component state instead of the app state, and that's where problems started to arise.

As of now, I cannot manage to populate the table. The header gets rendered but there's nothing else, and the only way I can make it show data is to make a small change in `Table.jsx` while `npm start` is running (such as adding or changing the output of any `console.log`) and saving the file. Only then, data is displayed.

I've been trying everything I could think of for about 2 days now (last thing I tried was wrapping `Table.jsx` into another component, but nothing changed).

I tried `console.log`ing all the steps where data is involved to try and debug this, but I'm failing to understand where the problem is. Here's the output when the app loads first:

[image: console.log output]

My code currently:

- utility function to fetch data from Firestore

```js
const parseData = async (db) => {
    const dataArray = [];
    const snapshot = db.collection('collection-name').get();

    snapshot.then(
        (querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                const document = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
                dataArray.push(document);
            });
        },
    );
    console.log('func output', dataArray);
    return dataArray;
};

export default parseData;
```

- Table.jsx

```js
import { useTable } from 'react-table';

const Table = ({ columns, data }) => {
    const tableInstance = useTable({ columns, data });
    console.log('table component data received', data);
    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow,
    } = tableInstance;

    return (
        // html boilerplate from https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/quick-start#applying-the-table-instance-to-markup
    );
};

export default Table;
```

- TableContainer.jsx

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import parseData from '../utils';
import Table from './Table';

const TableContainer = ({ db }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            const dataFromServer = await parseData(db);
            setData(dataFromServer);
            console.log('container-useEffect', dataFromServer);
        };
        getData();
    }, [db]);

    const columns = useMemo(() => [
        {
            Header: 'ID',
            accessor: 'id',
        },
        // etc...
    ], []);

    console.log('container data', data);

    return (
        <>
            <Table columns={columns} data={data} />
        </>
    );
};

export default TableContainer;
```

- App.jsx

```js
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';

import TableContainer from './components/TableContainer';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';

// ############ INIT FIRESTORE DB
const firestoreCreds = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
};
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(firestoreCreds);
}
const db = firebase.firestore();

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar title="This is madness" />
            <div>
                <TableContainer db={db} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Edit: in the end, using the suggestions below, this is the final solution I could come up with. I was annoyed by having to wrap the API call in an async func within `useEffect`, so this is what I did.

- utility function to fetch data from Firestore

```js
const parseData = (db) => {
    const snapshot = db.collection('collection_name').get();

    return snapshot.then(
        (querySnapshot) => {
            const dataArray = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                const document = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
                dataArray.push(document);
            });
            return dataArray;
        },
    );
};

export default parseData;
```

- TableContainer.jsx

Here I also added the flag `didCancel` within `useEffect` to avoid race conditions, according to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14326#issuecomment-472043812) and [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data) it seems to be a best practice.

```js
// imports

const TableContainer = ({ db }) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
    let didCancel = false;

        parseData(db)
            .then((dataFromServer) => (!didCancel && setData(dataFromServer)));

    return () => { didCancel = true; }
    }, [db]);

// ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `parseData` function this line `return dataArray;` is execute before the snapshot is resolved. You need to change `parseData` and return a `Promise` and resolve when data is ready:

```
const parseData = async (db) => {
    const dataArray = [];
    const snapshot = db.collection('collection-name').get();
    return new Promise(resolve => {
       snapshot.then(
        (querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                const document = { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
                dataArray.push(document);
            });
            resolve(dataArray); //--> resolve when data is ready
        },
    );
    })
   
};
```

Comment: This works, and I realize now my mistake. I didn't understand that the problem was in the utility function due to the fact that `console.log` was actually showing data, but I didn't know that it was just referencing a pointer instead of printing the string. I then used JSON.stringify and as you pointed out, the logs were empty.

What I don't understand is why I can't return `dataArray` from `parseData`, within the `.then()` block. Your solution works perfectly but it looks (from an ignorant perspective) very wordy. Is it the default way to handle these kind of things ?

Comment: @wtfzambo See my answer. It does (should do) the same thing.

Comment: @AKX I had tried your code too, but the issue I had with it was that `snapshot.map` is not a function. Snapshot is a promise and therefore the only thing I can do with it is use `.then`.

Answer (score 2):

In your TableContainer, you initialize `data` with an empty array. That's being sent along to Table until you finish getting `data` from your server. If you don't want that to happen, you should change your default (in useState) to something like `false` and explicitly handle that case (e.g. display "Please wait. Loading" if `data === false`).

Answer (score 1):

The asynchronicity in the `parseData` function is plain wrong (and the implementation a smidge too complex...). Reimplement it something like this...

```
const parseData = async (db) => {
    // Note `await` here.
    const snapshot = await db.collection('collection-name').get();
    return snapshot.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));
};

export default parseData;
```